# Why are classes with uninitialized member variables compilable in java?

Tags: java, variables, initialization

This question was asked in a test.And i was wondering what you think of it.

an uninitialized local member variable (say b) used in a private method.

"Why is it compilable?"

Edit:

```
class Class
{
    private int a=0; // this is an initialized member variable and I knew already that c# & java initializes all variables but that was NOT the question.
    private int b; // to me this is an uninitialized member variable
    private void Method()
    {
        b++; //no compiler error here in java. and the question was why is that so?
    }
}
```

I did not know that member variables are called attributes in java. I was more interested in what you think of  the question which i find weird. Of course compiler designers decided to do that way but the question was why is that compilable?I think teacher was questioning the rationale. But I stopped questioning teachers weird questions. Anyway, thanks for the answers.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "uninitialized member variable".  By definition, all member(instance) variables are initialized to zero/null unless explicitly set otherwise.

Comment: As to local variables, they must have values set before they are referenced, but do not need to be initialized where declared.

Answer (score 2):

"Member" is a term that is more commonly used in C++, but presumably refers to instance variables here. The answer is: Because instance variables have a *default* value according to the Java Language Specification ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5 ). (In contrast to local variables, which do *not* have a default value)

Comment: Yes, the term "local member variable" also confuses me.

Comment: The Java tutorial states, `You may also occasionally see the term "member" used as well. A type's fields, methods, and nested types are collectively called its members.`

Comment: Sure, there even is an interface `java.lang.reflect.Member` which is implemented by `Constructor`, `Field` and `Method`. It was not clear whether the question is about fields or local variables, or static fields or instance fields, but from the context, one could assume the latter.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by local member variable, you mean attribute?

Even if it is not initialized, it has a clear defined semantic. Objects will be initialized as `null`, numbers as 0 and booleans as `false`.

Whether it is good practice to use unassigned variables is disputable. By from the language perspective, at least you don't have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

An uninitialized variable is "compatible" because the specification allows for it and it is necessary because certain situations call for it.  For example consider a try..catch block where the variable inside the try catch must be used outside the block.

```
    BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
//Do something with br
```